# How to change where the output directory where the new images go

Tags: python-3.x

I have a small query I'm hoping someone can help me out within Python 3. I am resizing a dataset of 10000 images to all be 1000x1000 in dimension before I do any pytorch analysis with it. I just wanted to ask how I change my code to save the outgoing images to a new folder I have created ''train_resized'' instead of the same folder as the original files as it is doing now when I run. Thanks

```
# Testing dataset

from PIL import Image

import os, sys

path = (r'G:\My Drive\CATSVDOGS2.0\test1\\')
dirs = os.listdir( path )

def resize():
    for item in dirs:
        if os.path.isfile(path+item):
        im = Image.open(path+item)
        f, e = os.path.splitext(path+item)
        imResize = im.resize((1000,1000), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        imResize.save(f + ' resized.jpg', 'JPEG', quality=90)

resize()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your line

```
imResize.save(f + ' resized.jpg', 'JPEG', quality=90)
```

you're setting the path when using the variable `f`, as `f` uses the `path` variable you defined. A quick way to set the path is to do something like:

```
imResize.save('G:\\My Drive\\Path\\To\\Folder\\' + item + ' resized.jpg', 'JPEG', quality=90)
```

of course specify the path to be whatever you want. Untested as I don't have Python installed on my work machine, but that is the general gist.

Comment: Thanks that worked like a charm! Appreciate the assist. Yeah it didn't work due to the slashes but if you add 'r' before the string it makes it a raw string and fixes the issue too :)